# How to plot k-medoids results of time series in R?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm making a project connected with identifying dynamic of sales. That's how the piece of my database looks like http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img854/1958/zlco.jpg . There are three columns:

Product - present the group of product

Week - time since launch the product (week), first 26 weeks

Sales_gain - how the sales of product change by week

In the database there is 3302 observations = 127 time series

My aim is to cluster time series in groups which are going to show me different dynamic of sales. I used k-medoids algorithm (after transforming data with FFT/DWT) and I do not know how to present each cluster = grouped time series on different plots.

Can somebody tell me how should I do that?

Here is the code of clustering:

```
clustersalesGain = pam(t(salesGain), 8)
nazwy = as.character(nazwy)
cbind(nazwy,clustersalesGain$clustering)
```

I would like to present the output on different plots.

Comment: how about give each cluster a different color or line style, then plot them in one single chart?

Comment: that's my problem, cause I dont know how to define different color for each cluster. Can you help me with the procedure? Sorry for my incompetence, but it's my first time I deal with clustering in R.

Comment: the parameter _col=_ of lines.ts function is to control the color of the time series.

Comment: I am sorry, but still I dont know how to implement it. Cause after using 'cbind(nazwy,clustersalesGain$clustering)' i get the results:     nazwy                               
  [1,] "Akcesoria_dla_zwierząt"         "1"
  [2,] "Balsam"                         "1"
  [3,] "Baton_zbożowy"                  "2"
  [4,] "Bekon"                          "1"
etc.

How should I define - plot cluster 1 on the plot with red color? Can  you give me an example?

Comment: `tsdat <- ts(rt(200 * 8, df = 3), start = c(1961, 1), frequency = 12)

plot(tsdat, col='red')`

HTH

Comment: Still I cannot implement it... I tried with plotting clustersalesGain, but it does not show me time series, just performance. Can You consider my code an write an example to cluster one, defined by pam? I would be very gratefull

Answer (score 0):

k-medoids returns actual data points as cluster centers.

**Just visualize them the same way you visualize your data!**

(And if you havn't been visualizing your data, you better work on that now.)